# airflow saving previous task from the dag

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Good day,

I've faced with a problem.
I create a dag, which teakes data from `airflow.models.Variable`. Then i triggered task in webserver UI. All worked fine. After that i changed my variable. When i tried to access log of task that was triggered before (from UI), i got the message:

`Task [my_crazy_dag.supertask] doesn't seem to exist at the moment`

This task state is removed.
I would like to ask, if there a choice to save task, that it was available after i change the dag, to see it logs or run it again?